# Find the mean and variance of the total service time using the Poisson distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

> Customers arrive at a checkout counter in a department store according to a Poisson distribution at an average of seven per hour. If it takes approximately ten minutes to serve each customer, find the mean and variance of the total service time for customers arriving during a 1-hour period. (Assume that a sufficient number of servers are available so that no customer must wait for service.) Is it likely that the total service time will exceed $2.5$ hours?

Let $S$ be the total service time $= 10Y$.
What I have: 
$$E(S) = 10E(Y) = 70$$
$$V(S) = 100V(Y) = 700$$
$$P(S>150) = P(Y>15) = 1-P(Y\le 15) = 1-.998 = .002$$
So the event is very unlikely to occur.

Is my answer right?

Answer (score 1):

We can write $$S = \sum_{n=1}^{N}X_i$$

where $N$ is the number of customers that arrive within one hour and $X_i$ is the total service time for customer $i$.

The [law of total expectation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_iterated_expectations) states: $E_X[X] = E_Y[E_X[X|Y]]$ and so for this case it amounts to: $$E_S[S] = E_N[E_S[S|N]] = E_N[E_X[N\times X]] = E_N[N  E_X[X]]=E[N]E[X]$$.

In other words, your calculation of $E[S]$ is correct.  Now to get the variance we start with:

$$Var[S] = E[S^2]-E[S]^2 = E_N[E_S[S^2|N]]-\{E_N[E_S[S|N]]\}^2$$

$$=E[Var[S|N]+E[S|N]^2]+\{E_N[E_S[S|N]]\}^2$$

$$=E[Var[S|N]]+Var[E[S|N]] = E[N]Var[X]+E[X]^2Var[N]$$

$$=E[N]E[X^2]$$

Where the last equality follows from the equality of a Possion random variable's mean and variance.

Finally, to calculate the probability, invoke the central limit theorem  with your newly calculated $E[S]$ and $Var[S]$.

Comment: I have trouble for calculating E(Y^2)? Could you please help?

Comment: Do you mean $E_S[S^2|N]$?  Where are you getting stuck?  Remember that $E[X^2] = Var[X] + E[X]^2$ for any random variable $X$.

Comment: wait a minute...I think V(S) =V(10Y) = 10^2*V(Y) = 100V(Y) = 700 is right. Isn't it?

Comment: The question says it takes **approximately** 10 minutes to service each customer. To me that means it takes 10 minutes on average. I don't think we can assume it is always 10 minutes which leads to your answer.

Comment: What is your suggestion?

Comment: Please see my completed derivation of $Var[S]$ above. You can decide on your own what the interpretation ought to be, I gave you my belief above. Both interpretations fit into the equation since if you take the service time to be a constant then $E[X^2]=X^2$ does this make sense?